# Unable to connect to redis installed on my development host machine from development container

Tags: docker, redis, redis-cluster

I have a redis cluster running on my MacBook (localhost), I am easing my way into docker as part of my developer environment.

I also have things like MongoDB running on my host and am able to successfully connect to via `host.docker.internal`, at this time i'm not looking to containerize redis, or my other services

Im specifically getting errors that my server is somehow trying to connect using `127.0.0.1` when my code is definitely using `host.docker.internal`

this is happening on the current nodejs container, but also another ruby container - so something about redis is unhappy

```
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.186Z app:cache:client FATAL Redis Cluster Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30003
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.188Z app:cache:client FATAL Redis Cluster Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30001
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.189Z app:cache:client FATAL Redis Cluster Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30002
```

###### Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:16.16.0-buster as base

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock

FROM base as dev
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

###### docker-compose.dev.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  oauth:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: oauth
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
    environment:
      - RACK_ENV=docker
      - PORT=5050
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: yarn run nodemon ./src/index.js
```

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build
[+] Building 6.8s (17/17) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 245B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.8s
 => [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:443aab4ca21183e069e7d8b2dc68006594f40bddf1b15bbd83f5137bd93e80e2                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16.16.0-buster                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.5s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.9s
 => => transferring context: 3.52MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.9s
 => [base 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:16.16.0-buster@sha256:2e1b4542d4a06e0e0442dc38af1f4828760aecc9db2b95e7df87f573640d98cd                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [base 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [base 3/4] COPY package.json package.json                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [base 4/4] COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [dev 1/2] RUN yarn install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [dev 2/2] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     2.2s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     2.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2.0s
 => => writing image sha256:a297a1937c12a7403b12dec58a71c28df60caa0ee387daec51af2ffb0dc5968e                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/oauth_oauth                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container oauth  Recreated                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
Attaching to oauth
oauth  | yarn run v1.22.19
oauth  | $ NODE_ENV=docker yarn run nodemon ./src/index.js
oauth  | $ /app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon ./src/index.js
oauth  | [nodemon] 2.0.16
oauth  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
oauth  | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
oauth  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
oauth  | [nodemon] starting `node ./src/index.js`
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.161Z app:index INFO ⚡️ Successfully Started Express Server
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.162Z app:index INFO ⚡️ Environment: docker
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.163Z app:index INFO ⚡️ Node Version: v16.16.0
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.163Z app:index INFO ⚡️ Listening on: http://localhost:5050
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.163Z app:index INFO ⚡️ OS linux
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.186Z app:cache:client FATAL Redis Cluster Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30003
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.188Z app:cache:client FATAL Redis Cluster Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30001
oauth  | 2022-07-22T21:57:58.189Z app:cache:client FATAL Redis Cluster Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30002
```

---

More info:

Redis Cluster is ran by doing the following:
(i've been using this for several years, it works)
https://developer.redis.com/explore/redisinsight/cluster/

```
$ cd ~/Documents/dev/redis-6.2.6; ./utils/create-cluster/create-cluster start;
Starting 30001
Starting 30002
Starting 30003
Starting 30004
Starting 30005
Starting 30006
$ redis-cli -c -p 30001
127.0.0.1:30001> ping
PONG
```

i connected to the container to prove that host.docker.internal resolves to host

```
$ docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash
$ ping host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (192.168.65.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=0.182 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=37 time=0.275 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=37 time=0.230 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=37 time=0.516 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=5 ttl=37 time=0.540 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=6 ttl=37 time=0.560 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=7 ttl=37 time=0.566 ms
^C
--- host.docker.internal ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 138ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.182/0.409/0.566/0.161 ms
```

However, netstat doesnt return anything for `30001` only `30003`

```
$ netstat -a | grep 30001
(nothing)
```

```
$ netstat -a | grep 30003
tcp4       0      0  localhost.30003        localhost.51793        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.51793        localhost.30003        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  *.30003                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.30003                *.*                    LISTEN
```

---

the default config for redis when it starts is here

```bash
# Settings
BIN_PATH="/Users/aronlilland/Documents/dev/redis-6.2.6/src"
CLUSTER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=30000
TIMEOUT=2000
NODES=6
REPLICAS=1
PROTECTED_MODE=yes
ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS=""

# You may want to put the above config parameters into config.sh in order to
# override the defaults without modifying this script.

if [ -a config.sh ]
then
    source "config.sh"
fi

# Computed vars
ENDPORT=$((PORT+NODES))

if [ "$1" == "start" ]
then
    while [ $((PORT < ENDPORT)) != "0" ]; do
        PORT=$((PORT+1))
        echo "Starting $PORT"
        $BIN_PATH/redis-server --port $PORT  --protected-mode $PROTECTED_MODE --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes-${PORT}.conf --cluster-node-timeout $TIMEOUT --appendonly yes --appendfilename appendonly-${PORT}.aof --dbfilename dump-${PORT}.rdb --logfile ${PORT}.log --daemonize yes ${ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS}
    done
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Did you comment out this line in your `redis.conf` file and restart? `# bind 127.0.0.1 ::1`

Comment: You should be able to see if Redis is listening on all interfaces (i.e. 0.0.0.0) or just localhost (i.e. 127.0.0.1) with `sudo netstat -tunlp`

Comment: redis.conf is not uncommented -- `bind 127.0.0.1 -::1`

Comment: You need the hash at the start.

Comment: unfortunately did not work ☹️

Comment: If you run the `netstat` command I suggested, is **Redis** listening on 0.0.0.0 port 6379 ?

Comment: If you are trying to connect to **Redis** running on your Mac from within a docker container, it will need to use the IP address of your Mac, not 127.0.0.1 which is shorthand for *"the local machine"*, i.e. something inside the container.

Comment: redis is not listening on port 6379, its running in cluster mode on `30001`, `30002`, `30003`, `30004`, `30005`, `30006` -- ive been using it for several years and it works while not running in the container, so its absolutely on. running `netstat -a | grep 30003` returns several established connections on tcp4, and 2 listening connections on tcp6 - other systems are able to connect using `host.docker.internal` instead of localhost, its redis that doing something weird

Comment: more details added to OP

Comment: Redis is running on 127.0.0.1 which means it will not allow connections from docker containers or from any other machines on your network. It needs to listen on **all interfaces** for connections, i.e. on 0.0.0.0. Both `netstat` and `redis-cli` are telling you Redis is on 127.0.0.1

Comment: Same as here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/72882529/2836621

Comment: my mongodb instance is listening on localhost:27017 and docker is able to connect to it without it being bound to 0.0.0.0 - binding to 0.0.0.0 is highly vulnerable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572003/redis-cluster-create-replicas-bind-public-ip there is no reason for my entire home network/work network to see redis as an open port, the purpose of docker for dev is to make a local network that doesn't leave the box

Comment: after running some tests by installing the redis-cli in the container, i confirmed that the container is in fact able to reach the host redis nodes using `host.docker.internal`, what I believe is happening is that the redis clusters themselves are responding back with their localhost master/slave url's which are `127.0.0.1` so when the nodejs client tries to use the url provided from the redis response, it fails